# How do I bake a bone animation that has a constraint?

Tags: animation, bones, constraints, baking

I have a BVH where the leg has a wobble in the x rotation so I added a limit rotation constraint to remove the wobble.

How do I convert the bone's pose with the constraint to just keyframes of its position but without the constraint?

Answer (score 5):

In *Pose Mode* go to menu *Pose > Animation > Bake Action*

Check: *Visual Keying*
Check: *Clear Constraints*
*Bake Data: Pose*
*OK*

The constraints will be removed from the bone but instead the bone will be keyframed to act as if the constraint is affecting its motion.

Comment: Is there a way we can bake ALL actions instead of a single one?