# Is there a way to record absolute position?

Tags: animation, keyframes, constraints

When using a Child-Of constraint, I sometimes want to toggle it off in an animation, but still make a new animation based off of where an object was when the constraint was active.

When I do this however, the object reverts to the position it was before it ever had the constraint, and copying the pose while the constraint is active and then pasting it doesn't change anything. So, how else do I record where an object is during a constraint and then make the object move from that same position after the constraint is off??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I bake a bone animation that has a constraint?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97649/how-do-i-bake-a-bone-animation-that-has-a-constraint)

Comment: I didn't ask for baking though, that's something you imposed on me, I don't want to bake it I just want to add a keyframe.

Comment: Bake a single frame keeping the constraints, then hide the constraint. Wouldn't that be what you want to do?

Comment: Ah, probably a more fitting solution would be to select the bone, then Ctrl A > *Apply Visual Transform*, then set the keyframe. Could you try that?

Comment: [This would be another possible duplicate.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/118097/30849).

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2533/599